# Shrinkage Parameter for LASSO (glmnet package in R)

Tags: r, logistic, glmnet, regularization

I am using `glmnet` package in `R`-software to build a Binary Logistic Regression with the LASSO. I have used the following link as a reference:

https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html#log

When printing the model as can be seen even in the above link I am getting a 3 column matrix where the first column represents the number of non-zero coef, the 2nd column the %deviance and 3rd the value of lambda.

```
## 
## Call:  glmnet(x = x, y = y, weights = c(rep(1, 50), rep(2, 50)), alpha = 0.2,      nlambda = 20) 
## 
##       Df  %Dev  Lambda
##  [1,]  0 0.000 7.94000
##  [2,]  4 0.179 4.89000
##  [3,]  7 0.444 3.01000
##  [4,]  7 0.657 1.85000
##  [5,]  8 0.785 1.14000
##  [6,]  9 0.854 0.70300
##  [7,] 10 0.887 0.43300
##  [8,] 11 0.902 0.26700
##  [9,] 14 0.910 0.16400
## [10,] 17 0.914 0.10100
## [11,] 17 0.915 0.06230
## [12,] 17 0.916 0.03840
## [13,] 19 0.916 0.02360
## [14,] 20 0.916 0.01460
## [15,] 20 0.916 0.00896
## [16,] 20 0.916 0.00552
## [17,] 20 0.916 0.00340
```

A large valye of lambda indicates relatively relaxed constraint as this allows more variables in the model. In the above example we have for example lambda = 0.00340 with 20 non-zero coef while lambda = 7.94 with 0 non zero coef. How is this possible?

Comment: Lambda is the shrinkage/penalty/regularisation parameter. Larger lambda, stronger regularisation and therefore more shrinkage.

Comment: The objective that you minimise is $$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i -  \boldsymbol{\beta}^T\mathbf{x}_i)^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^p\vert\beta_j\vert.$$ The object is to minimise the function, so if you increase the size of the penalty part $$ \lambda\sum_{j=1}^p\vert\beta_j\vert,$$ that will force the parameters to be smaller, since you put a higher price on the size of the coefficients.

Comment: Also if you want logistic regression, you have to specify family="binomial", in the call to glmnet, and if you set alpha to another value than the default (alpha=1), you will get elastic net regularisation (if 0 < alpha < 1), or ridge (alpha=0).

Comment: @SimonBogeBrant - Yes agreed for the family="binomial", I am more trying to understand the output. Still not clear enough because  for example lambda = 0.00340 with 20 non-zero coef while lambda = 7.94 with 0 non-zero coef. How is that even possible? The penaty part for the LASSO pushes the coeff to 0 no?

Comment: Yes, so if lambda is large, you will have fewer non-zero coefficients. If lambda is small, you would get more non-zero coefficients. Lambda=0 would correspond to the maximum likelihood solution.

Comment: aaa yes now I get it...thanks a lot @SimonBogeBrant

Comment: @SimonBogeBrant looks like the correct answer to me; why not post it as one?